# Creating type dynamically at runtime for dapper querymultiple Read method using Reflection

Tags: reflection, types, dapper

I'm trying to pass type of class dynamically at runtime. The below code give error at code section:

```
    object newObject Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(t.GetGenericArguments()[0].FullName));
    data.Read<newObject>();
```

I've also tried

```
    data.Read<Type.GetType(t.GetGenericArguments()[0].FullName)>();
```

Here's the complete method:

```
    public object FetchMultipleRecordSet(string storedProcedure, IList<QueryParameter> parameterCollection, object dataList)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(storedProcedure))
        {
            using (SqlConnection sql = CreateDatabaseConnection())
            {
                DynamicParameters dynamicParameter = ConvertToDynamicParameters(parameterCollection);
                var data = sql.QueryMultiple(storedProcedure, dynamicParameter, null, null, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

                PropertyInfo[] properties = dataList.GetType().GetProperties();
                foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
                {
                    Type t = property.PropertyType;
                    if (t.BaseType == null && t.IsGenericType && t.Namespace == "System.Collection.Generic")
                    {
                        //property.SetValue(data.Read());
                        object newObject = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(t.GetGenericArguments()[0].FullName));
                        data.Read<>();    
                    }
                    else if (t.Namespace != "System")
                    {
                        //typeCollection.Add(Type.GetType(t.FullName));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return dataList;
    }
```

Here's the view model that I want to use:

```
    public class ResultCollection
    {
        public IList<ShortCodeList> ShortCodeListCollection { get; set; }
        public DateTime CurrentDate { get; set; }
        public UserMembershipPlan UserMembershipPlanRecord { get; set; }
        public IList<EmailRecipients> EmailRecipientsCollection { get; set; }
    }
```

I need to pass the type into data.Read() so that the property which is in generic form could get mapped with the result set. If I pass "newObject" or "Type.GetType(t.GetGenericArguments()[0].FullName)" still it gives me error. This might look clumsy but I think it should work.

Answer (score 4):

At the moment, the typed API to dapper uses generics. There is an untyped API but you would need to do your own member mapping. To call a generic method via a type you need to use MethodInfo on the generic method, MakeGenericMethod and Invoke. There is also a way to spoof it with `dynamic`, by adding a shim method in your code, akin to:

```
dynamic template = ...  // activator etc
Evil(template, otherArgs...);

Evil<T>(T template, otherArgs...) {
    use some <T> method etc here
}
```

---

As a more complete example, the following works:

```
public void TypeBasedViaDynamic()
{
    Type type = GetSomeType();

    dynamic template = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    dynamic actual = CheetViaDynamic(template,
        "select @A as [A], @B as [B]", new { A = 123, B = "abc" });
    ((object)actual).GetType().IsEqualTo(type);
    int a = actual.A;
    string b = actual.B;
    a.IsEqualTo(123);
    b.IsEqualTo("abc");
}

T CheetViaDynamic<T>(T template, string query, object args)
{
    return connection.Query<T>(query, args).SingleOrDefault();
}
static Type GetSomeType()
{
    return typeof(SomeType);
}
public class SomeType
{
    public int A { get;set; }
    public string B { get;set; }
}
```

Note that this starts from just a `Type`, and populates an instance via a dummy instance (via `Activator`) and `dynamic`. Not pretty, but it works. I have, however, also just pushed some changes to dapper that accept a `Type` instance as a parameter, making the following also work - without the need for these hacks:

```
public void TypeBasedViaType()
{
    Type type = GetSomeType();

    dynamic actual = connection.Query(type,
        "select @A as [A], @B as [B]", new { A = 123, B = "abc" }
        ).FirstOrDefault();
    ((object)actual).GetType().IsEqualTo(type);
    int a = actual.A;
    string b = actual.B;
    a.IsEqualTo(123);
    b.IsEqualTo("abc");
}
```

And multi-grid readers too:

```
public void TypeBasedViaTypeMulti()
{
    Type type = GetSomeType();

    dynamic first, second;
    using(var multi = connection.QueryMultiple(
        "select @A as [A], @B as [B]; select @C as [A], @D as [B]",
        new { A = 123, B = "abc", C = 456, D = "def" }))
    {
        first = multi.Read(type).Single();
        second = multi.Read(type).Single();
    }
    ((object)first).GetType().IsEqualTo(type);
    int a = first.A;
    string b = first.B;
    a.IsEqualTo(123);
    b.IsEqualTo("abc");

    ((object)second).GetType().IsEqualTo(type);
    a = second.A;
    b = second.B;
    a.IsEqualTo(456);
    b.IsEqualTo("def");
}
```

Note that the `dynamic` in these new API examples is purely for test convenience; `dynamic` is not an important part of the approach.

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for answering the question. I'd started working onto some other concept. It will be great if you could fill me in the part that you added over here. I'd almost gave up hopes for any answer from here.

Comment: @Deepak have been on mobile all weekend - will add an example when at a pc

Comment: Marc, thank you. I was getting deep in the weeds of reflection, like invoking dynamic methods from `MethodInfo` searches and similar, and you have made this so much easier. Unfortunately, my hair is already pulled out, but I am sure it will grow back now.